# Batch File that Closes after a Program Closes

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently using a batch file to launch a non-steam game, and I would like the batch file to close itself as soon as the game closes.

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Windows"

start "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.Dayton_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppStateOfDecay2

@pause
```

The reason that it has to stay up while the game is running is so that Steam can tell my Friends that I'm playing the game, and it stops as soon as the batch file is closed.

Edit: I should clarify why I'm using Explorer.exe, that's because I'm spoofing Explorer.exe within steam as an executable, when really the path is directing towards the UWP app

Comment: Get rid of the `@pause` and the batch script should automatically close when the executable closes.

Comment: See, the issue there is that it closes the bat file right away without a pause, so because the batch file is closed, it isn't showing the status on Steam.

Comment: Change `start` to `start ""`, enter `start /?` at the command prompt to find out why.

Comment: while I appreciate that suggestion @Compo, whenever I do it like that: `@echo off

cd "C:\Windows"

start "" "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.Dayton_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppStateOfDecay2` the batch file still closes itself.

Comment: It's not closing because of my advice though, because that is the correct syntax, as you should agree if you followed my advice and read the usage information. The first item inside doublequotes is read as the title of the spawned window, my advice gives it an empty title to prevent that. _That means your explorer.exe  command without my advice, wasn't a command at all!_

Comment: So what you're saying is that your advice prevents further issues but does not solve the problem, albeit helpful

Comment: Don't use the start command.

Comment: @Squashman without the start command it still closes right away instead of when the application closes. `@echo off

cd "C:\Windows"

"C:\Windows\explorer.exe" shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.Dayton_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppStateOfDecay2`

Comment: Probably can't be done then.  I would assume it is spawning a separate process and returning control back to the parent process.

Comment: is there not a way to check what process is running and close it if the process (once identified) is in fact terminated?

Comment: You'd have to constantly monitor the output of `tasklist`, but I guess it's possible.

Comment: Explorer.exe will release control back to the calling process after it has launched. You can test that real easy just opening a folder.  So you could attempt to monitor the task and keep looping back until it is no longer seen in tasklist: `tasklist | findstr /I /C:"myprocess" >nul 2>&1 && GOTO LOOP || GOTO :EOF`  I would advise you put a timeout command at the top of the loop as well.